# Make a list the elements of the subgroup <a> in S7

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the permutation $$a=\begin{pmatrix}1234567\\3276514\end{pmatrix}$$ in S7 .List the elements of the subgroup  in S7.

Hello, I just graduated from high school and in my summer time I'm reading about abstract algebra I want to learn more about the subject, but I do not understand how the book explains the part of permutation maybe I need a course, but I'll take it on University. Someone could explain or help me with this problem so I can understand better.

Comment: Do you understand the notation for $a$? Do you know what a subgroup generated by an element looks like?

Comment: If you need more material on permutation groups in crash course http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math47aF08/M47F08Note09aa.pdf

Comment: I am off to bed, but I wanted to say that you are doing *exactly* the right thing. Ask, ask, ask, ask, ask, and ask some more. If something doesn't make sense, ask. Even if you don't know exactly what your question is, try to ask it anyway, or at least say you're confused. You'll be a great math student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a=\begin{pmatrix}1234567\\3276514\end{pmatrix}$.  I assume you know what that means.  $1$ maps to $3$, $2$ maps to $2$, $3$ to seven and so on.

$a^2 = a\circ a =\begin{pmatrix}1234567\\3276514\end{pmatrix}\circ \begin{pmatrix}1234567\\3276514\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1234567\\3276514\end{pmatrix}\circ  \begin{pmatrix}3276517\\7241536\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1234567\\7241536\end{pmatrix}$

This is $1$ mapping to $3$ which gets mapped to $7$.  $2$ mapping to $2$ to $2$.  $3$ mapping to $7$ which gets mapped to $4$. etc. (i.e. applying the permutation... and then applying it again.

And so on:

$a^3 = a^2\circ a = \begin{pmatrix}1234567\\4263571\end{pmatrix}$

$a^4 = \begin{pmatrix}1234567\\62173543\end{pmatrix}$

$a^5 =\begin{pmatrix}1234567\\1234567\end{pmatrix}=Identity$.

So these are a group of $5$ permutations.

It'd be easier and more enlightening to use the notation $(abc)(de)(f)$ to indicate $a$ goes to $b$, $b$ to $c$, and $c$ to $a$, while $d$ goes to $e$ and $e$ to $d$ while $f$ goes to $f$.

so $a = \begin{pmatrix}1234567\\3276514\end{pmatrix}$ can be written as $(13746)(2)(5)$ which means $1$ maps to $3$, $3$ to $7$.

$b = a^2 = (17634)(2)(5)$

$c = a^3 = (14367)(2)(5)$

$d = a^4 = (16473)(2)(5)$

$I = a^5 = (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)$

It's easy to verify that $a^i\circ a^j = a^{i+j \mod 5}$ and that $a^{i}\circ a^{5-i \mod 5} = I$ this is a equivalent to the group $\mathbb Z_5$ with $k \in \mathbb Z_5 \approx a^k \in <a>$ and with $j+k \mod 5 \approx a^j\circ a^k$.

I'm not sure to what extent you are familiar with group theory.

Answer (score 1):

The key step is writing the permutation into disjoint cycles:
$$
a=(1\,3\,7\,4\,6)(2)(5)
$$
See [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1924432/62967) for a description.

Then the distinct powers of $a$ are
\begin{align}
a^0&=\text{identity} \\
a^1&=(1\,3\,7\,4\,6)(2)(5) \\
a^2&=(1\,7\,6\,3\,4)(2)(5) \\
a^3&=(1\,4\,3\,6\,7)(2)(5) \\
a^4&=(1\,6\,4\,7\,3)(2)(5)
\end{align}
If you want to write, say, $a^3$ in the “matrix form”, recall that each element has its image at its immediate right (bouncing back when the parenthesis is found):
$$
a^3=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
4 & 2 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The notation

$$a = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & \cdots & b_n \\ c_1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_n \end{pmatrix}$$

denotes a function with $a(b_1) = c_1, a(b_2) = c_2,\dots,a(b_n) = c_n$. This is usually given with $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, \dots, a_n = n$ but if you think about it, the order that the columns are given in doesn't matter. That is,

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\3&2&7&6&5&1&4\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{pmatrix} 3&2&7&6&5&1&4\\7&2&4&1&5&3&6 \end{pmatrix}$$

denote the same function. This is helpful because $a^2(i) = a(a(i)) = i$ and we can easily compute this by stacking the two matrices on top of each other:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\3&2&7&6&5&1&4\end{pmatrix} \\ \begin{pmatrix} 3&2&7&6&5&1&4\\7&2&4&1&5&3&6 \end{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\7&2&4&1&5&3&6 \end{pmatrix} = a^2. $$

Notice that if you apply $a$ to $1$ you get $a(1) = 3$ and then if you apply $a$ again you get $a(a(1)) = a(3) = 7$ and the same works for $a(a(2)) = 2$ and $a(a(3)) = 4$ and so on.

Thus you can compute products with this stacking technique. Since the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ generated by $a$ is nothing but the set of powers of $a$, this lets you compute the subgroup.

Note that this description of the subgroup generated by $a$ is only valid for a finite group. For an infinite group you need to add in $a^{-1}$ and its powers. The reason you can avoid this for finite groups is because in that case, $a^{-1}$ is always equal to a positive power of $a$.